# I want to add Listview in second page of ViewPager In android

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have ViewPagerwitch shows some Images on first page,but on the second page i want to show some images in listview, Confusing about how to make separate page setting in layout.
Here is ViewPager method per for adding pages

```
// Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
```

here is adapter

```
 private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

Screen slider ViewPager  class

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    // Set the title view to show the page number.
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
            getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change getItem at ScreenSlidePagerAdapter. At ScreenSlideSecondPageFragment you inflate layout for second page.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    
    switch (position) {               
    case 0: 
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    case 1: 
        return ScreenSlideSecondPageFragment.create(position);
    
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```